# Android: Trying to fill data in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

This is a bizarre error I am getting, because when I initially created this it worked just fine. I've spent quite a bit of time working through this trying to figure out what changed to make it stop working. The setup I used I borrowed from Android's official website's [Notepad exercises](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html).

```
 private void fillData() {
    Log.e("Progress Check", "fillData() method");
    mCursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllContacts();
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    String[] from = new String[] {TagDBAdapter.KEY_NAME, TagDBAdapter.KEY_USERNAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_image};
    ContactListAdapter contacts = new ContactListAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_view, mCursor, from, to);
    this.setListAdapter(contacts);
}
```

ContactListAdapter is just an extension of the ListAdapter method with an altered method for image display. This `filldata()` method does not fill the listview as it should... The `fetchAllContacts()` method hasn't been changed at all. I guess I'm just looking for a fresh set of eyes to see if anything stands out as something that could cause the issue in this code. Again, the problem is simply that the listview is not being populated. If there is any code you'd like to see that I haven't provided please ask, I want to avoid a code dump in the initial question. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the ContactListAdapter extend the ListAdapter class, have it extend the CursorAdapter class instead:   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need a ListAdapter for this, and it worked for me just fine before I just need to find where the issue is occuring.